# Develop a music player android app with swipe feature in two weeks

Tags: java, android, project, development-environment, audio-player, android-music-player

I have to develop a music player application, and in this app different activities has to be swiped through (same interface as google play music where you swipe through different parts). 
I want to have just one page (main page), with different tabs where I can swipe through. 
Since I'm also new to android development (familiar with java though). I have difficulties understanding are these tabs different activities, do I need to use fragments etc. I'm so lost on how to start building the actual app (start with interface, activities etc.). 
I would be grateful if someone could give me some advice and introduce me to some good tutorials.

Thanks.

Comment: This is asking for suggestions which is not what SO is for. You should try something and then ask a specific question.

Comment: But I just wanted to get an idea of what is the best way to start developing this app in such a limited time in the best way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a link from google developers on how to implement sliding tabs like google play.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tRg_eDfQ8fk

And this is an excellent tutorial to build a music player.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/

Integrate both and you will have your app.